# Writing a C function called CalculateOddEven, which takes a pointer to an integer number a and actual integers b and c

Tags: c, linux

I've this doubt with my assignment, which I've tried to do it but I don't think the code is right, so if anyone can help me out with it. 
The question is that I've to write a C function called `CalculateOddEven`, which takes a `pointer` to an
integer number `a` and actual integers `b` and `c`, the function should return and
actual integer. The function should generate a random number between `b` and
`c`, and then export the closest even number (either the number itself or the
previous number), while returning the closest positive number (either the
number itself or the next number).

For completeness you must seed the random number generator in your
function.

`The algorithm Must NOT use modulo, if statements, case statements, ternary
operators, or any other form of selection control.`

`Hint : Use bitwise operators`

```
int CalculateOddEven()
{
    int * a;
    int b, c;
    int count = 1;
    b = 5;
    c = 20;
    int n, num, e;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         num = (rand() %
                   (c - b + 1)) + b;
         }
        n = num & 1;

        while(n != 0){
            e = num - 1;
            n = e & 1;
        }
        printf("%d", e);

    return num;
}


int main()
{

    srand(time(0));

    printf(" %d", CalculateOddEven());

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried this code but I need to get it all in one function and get the results accurate and the results are not constant.

Comment: I have already seen this peculiar phrasing "and actual integers b and c". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55658840/can-any-one-give-hint-for-this-question-using-bitwise-operator

Comment: You're using the modulo operator.  `rand() % ...`.  I'm not sure why your instructor considers that to be in the same class as all the flow control keywords/operators, but nevertheless, it's included in the list of things you can't use.  As for your answer, you're on the right track with `n = n & 1`. You might try writing out the binary expansion of these numbers: `(5, 4), (17, 16), and (13, 12)`. What could you do in each case to turn the odd number into the corresponding even number that, if applied to the *even* number wouldn't change anything?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some confusion here because returning "the closest positive number" using only bitwise operations does not make any sense -- it's impossible.  I suspect your problem is really asking for the "closest even and odd numbers" in which case the algorithm is quite simple.

```
// Closest even number, gives num - 1 if num is odd.  (assumes num is positive)
mask = ~1; // 1111 1111 1111 1110
even = num & mask;

// Closest odd number, gives num + 1 if num is even.  (assumes num is positive)
mask = 1; // 0000 0000 0000 0001
odd = num | mask;
```

Comment: It's a homework question. Don't just give them the entire solution; give them a hint that helps them figure it out on their own.  Or if you do give them the whole solution, explain *why* it's the solution so they learn something more than just how to solve one specific contrived problem.